# Using Google Map tiles in Arcgis Android sdk

Tags: android, google-maps, arcgis

I want to develop and android app to show arcgis rest services on map. My requirement is to show Google map as base map.
I am using arcgis android sdk.

I read a blog on below link:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/7fa9wuMW990

My question is:
Can i use Google map tiles url to create TileServiceLayer of Google Map.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Google Maps terms you cant. It's not a technical problem, just a licensing one.

Comment: thanks... So is there any way around to use Google Map as a basemap in arcgis android sdk.

Comment: mmm you can do it anyway (tiles are publicly available) but it's against the terms of service. Why do you want to use googlemaps and not openstreetmap or other free services? There is also MS Virtual earth (the ancestor of Bing) which is freely available, check on NASA WorldWind references, NASA exposes a server with those tiles, freely available

Comment: Well googlemaps is the requirement...bt surely will give a try to your suggestion...Thanks alot...

Comment: The look & feel of Google Map is far much better than any other map avialable.